# Solr search top level and nested records

Tags: solr

I'm looking to setup a Solr search system which returns only top level records but also searches across the children (returning their parent record).

I'm running Solr 8.8.1 with a sample of the schema as follows

```
<field name="solr_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="path" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />

<fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" />
<field name="nest_path" type="_nest_path_" />
```

And a sample parent/child record like this, noting that some records have no children

```
{
  "dc_identifier_s": "41ef95d3cbc8473888d1734412bf82f0-4",
  "dc_title_s": "CRB_Hydrologic",
  "solr_type":"parent"
    "_childDocuments_": [
    {

      "dc_identifier_s": "41ef95d3cbc8473888d1734412bf82f0_0-4",
      "dc_title_s": "CR HUC1"
      "solr_type":"child"
    }]
}
```

I've been following the instructions here (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/searching-nested-documents.html) but as 'nest_path' doesn't populate, I've opted to use a custom field 'solr_type' which I set to either 'parent' or 'child'

Any guidance in how to search across all records but restrict results to the top level and the parents of child records would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The best attempt I've had at present is using the fq parameter with ```{!parent which='solr_type:parent'}``` but this seams to only allow searching through the parents. Adding the documented *:* (e.g. ```{!parent which='solr_type:parent *:*'}```) searches through both but also returns both parent and child records at the top level.

Comment: You could probably use Solr's Result Grouping (https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_0/result-grouping.html) for this but I think you'll need to have children and parent documents at the same level (i.e. no children documents but rather identify children by a specific field like you did with `solr_type`)

Comment: Thanks for your response @HectorCorrea. I'd like to keep the parent child relationship but it's nice to know this option exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the root documents, but to find (search) based on matches in child documents, and perhaps matches in root docs too?  This is a straight-forward application of the "parent" query parser as [described in the guide](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/searching-nested-documents.html#parent-query-parser); something like this:

```
&q={!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*" v=$q.nest}
&q.nest=real user query goes here
```

You didn't characterize what your queries otherwise like (what would go in q.nest above; an arbitrary named param I made up) -- maybe edismax or who knows what.  If you need to restrict matches to certain documents (say simple field=value or spatial maybe), you'll need to compose a more interesting query in there; you can't use filter queries (`fq`) because filter queries filter documents that `q` matches, which is only root documents.  So `q.nest` might be something like `+{!geofilt} +field:value  +{!edismax v=$q.user}`
I recommend using a more recent version of Solr than 8.0 (you refer to 8.0 docs) but I believe 8.0 will work nonetheless.  I especially don't advise earlier versions for nested docs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion David. I have been attempting with '_nest_path_' but  this  field really doesn't want to populate ( i.e query params  ```q=-_nest_path_:*``` returns all records , not just parents) . Using the 'solr_type:parent' option, I see that the childdocs are retained when calling with params ```q=solr_type:parent&fl=dc_identifier_s,[child]```.  I still haven't been able to succeed with this method and following your suggestion with params ```fl=dc_identifier_s,[child]&q={!parent which="*:* solr_type:parent" v=$q.nest} q.nest='minnow'``` with 'minnow' being an anywhere search.

Comment: This portion of what you showed: `which="*:* solr_type:parent"` doesn't seem right.  Remove the `*:*` part, which was used in the other example for a quirky Lucene limitation of pure negative queries -- not applicable to `solr_type:parent`.  Also I see tho the left of `q.nest` you have a space and thus it's a part of the q param.  I intended that as a new parameter, thus put an ampersand.  Note that direct URL browser manipulation can have issues: ex: the plus in `+*:*` will be interpreted as a space for URL encoding.  Non-issue when calling web APIs in code.

Comment: Having identified a few issues (Thanks @David Smiley), the below query works with defType=lucene in solrconfig, searching across parents and children  (note %2B used in place of + signs)```http://localhost:8983/solr/b-core/select?fl=dc_identifier_s,[child]&q= {!parent which=solr_type:parent v=$q.child} OR {!edismax v=$q.user}&q.child= %2Bsolr_type:child  %2B{!edismax v=$q.user}
&q.user=RG_HUBData_gdb``` looking at json https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wZoCZDUS7evpA8ssSvSB1WlWmvNgp_wE/view?usp=sharing One issue is that child records are returned instead of just their parents and root docs

Comment: With more input (Thanks again @David Smiley), the inclusion of ```"fq": "solr_type:parent"```, ```"fl": "dc_identifier_s,[child childFilter=$childFilter]"```  and ```"childFilter": "{!edismax v=$q.user}"``` works as expected by looking through both parent and child records but restricting the results to parents and the parents of matching children.